# How do I remove this Schlage double-cylinder deadbolt with no visible screws?

Tags: doors, hardware

[image]
Does anyone know how to remove this dead bolt that has no screw heads to use a screw driver? Here's a picture below.

Comment: Do you have a rotary multitool? (Dremel or equivalent)

Comment: That's the outside.  The removable screws are opposite on the inside.    If the burger could take the screws out.....

Answer (score 6):

Those are just metal "caps" that push into the screw heads..

The screws are located under those metal "pins"
The metal pins are actually screws that have metal caps pushed into them so they look like you can't unscrew them.  Take a very sharp small screw driver and pry under those caps and they will pop off revealing the screw head.

See here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kxtUFCHXBF0

Comment: Get one of those compressed air stun guns of the type used by bad hombre Xavier Bardem in "No Country for Old Men", BUT don't have anybody looking through the keyhole from the other side. One trigger pull and the job is done!

Answer (score 1):

### From the other side

It would be a super terrible lock manufacturer that put the screws on the "thief side" of the door.  You put them on the authorized-resident side.

Comment: Seems that this is a double-cylinder unit. Both sides are thief sides.

Comment: @isherwood - actually, if you think about it, the protruding part of the deadbolt in a double is always on the inside. Flush part on the outside to prevent monkey-wrenching.

Comment: Double cylinder jobs still have sides, I am assuming this is the outdoor side because of weather damage.

Comment: @isherwood Double-cylinder locks (to the extent they may still be legal) are for preventing the burglar from unlatching the bolt, not for preventing the burglar from removing the lock entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar lock in our home. Those are caps as another poster said. A putty knife or slim screwdriver should pop them off, revealing screws.

And yes, the protruding part is always inside. The external piece is almost always flush or near flush. But never with screws showing.

Grandpa was a fireman and locksmith. Had I not grown up in his shop, I would have been in the same boat wondering how to get them off.

Answer (score 0):

Some of these use a 5/64 Allen wrench