# Help to remove Schlage deadbolt

Tags: deadbolt

I need to remove a Schlage double-cylinder deadbolt from our front door. Problem is, there is no visible way to remove it. There is a hole on one side and a pin with no head on the right. This deadbolt does not have caps covering screws not same as another user's post

I've tried this and that, but nothing worked. I've enclosed a picture of lock (hole on left and pin on right)

[image]

The only person who might have know anything is no longer with us, any ideas with how to remove deadbolt without destroying door would be appreciated.

Comment: What does the other side of the lock look like?  Usually locks are removed from the non-secured side of the door.

Comment: @KeithProcter Double cylinder, so there is no non-secured side. The other side likely has no holes, being the more-secure side.

Comment: It might be the same as this:  https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/122733/how-do-i-remove-this-schlage-double-cylinder-deadbolt-with-no-visible-screws

References:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kxtUFCHXBF0

Comment: I wish there were caps like that but only a metal pin or peg on one side hole on other. pin or peg is flush with metal

Comment: it kinda looks like they use an SHCS, one on each side so you have to remove both to remove the unit.  Get some allen keys.  Is this a run of the mill residential grade Home Depot find, or is this one of their fancy Class 1 units, Primus etc.?

Comment: It's possible that the right side is a plug hiding a screw.  The left side may be missing the plug.  The picture doesn't have enough resolution to see the left side clearly, but it may be a screw with part of the head broken off, or someone may have previously tried to drill it out.  Or it could even be a security screw that requires a special bit.

Comment: I went ahead and got a lock smith left side with hole was hex key screw right side he used a dremel to grove it and twisted it off. $64.00 later, I'm happy! Thanks All!