# How to remove older Schlage deadbolt?

Tags: lock, deadbolt

I just bought a house and want to replace the locks. Unfortunately, on door has what appears to be an older Schlage double cylinder deadbolt that I can't figure out how to remove. I've tried prying faceplates off with no success. Internet searches talk about screw caps but these don't seem to be capping anything and I can't pry them out. I tried going in from the door edge, but the plate there seems to be attached to the inner mechanism and I couldn't get it out.

Does anyone know how I can remove this lock with destroying the door?

Image of the inside attached. The outside looks the same but without the two depressions on either side of the key.

[image: Schlage deadbolt with no visible screws]

Comment: The two depressions on the inside **are** the screw caps. That's why they are inside.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove this Schlage double-cylinder deadbolt with no visible screws?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/122733/how-do-i-remove-this-schlage-double-cylinder-deadbolt-with-no-visible-screws)  You can either pry harder, or buy an overpriced (unless you are a locksmith and would have repeat uses for it) tool that makes them easier to remove, evidently.

Comment: You'll destroy the screw caps removing them, but fyi, you can take the entire deadbolt out of the door, bring it to a locksmith (with key!) and have them inexpensively re-key it. If the key blanks all around the house are the same (in other words, you can't mix Kwikset and Schlage), you can get all your locks rekeyed same this way.

Comment: This is a repeat question, I will delete my answer. The video in the original answer is poor quality, but it does provide the detail for the removal of the caps.